# How to link UWP Class Library into an WPF Application?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, uwp

**How to link UWP Class Library into an WPF Application?**

I have created an UWP Class Library with a single test class. I have an WPF .NET application which wants to consume that class library. What are the steps I need to follow?

Following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jms3C-J-m2M), I wanted to add library `MyLib` in my Application `MyApp`. But I am finding following compiler errors,

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error NU1201  Project MyLib is not compatible with netcoreapp3.1
> (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1). Project MyLib supports:
> uap10.0.19041 (UAP,Version=v10.0.19041)   MyApp C:\Users....\MyApp.csproj

##UPDATE

After adding following code,

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <AssetTargetFallback>uap10.0.19041</AssetTargetFallback>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MyLib\MyLib.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

as suggested by TamBui in the answer, I am getting build error. However there have been two compiler warnings from the beginning. Sharing if it can give any clue,

> 1. Warning    NETSDK1137  It is no longer necessary to use the
>    Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop SDK. Consider changing the Sdk
>    attribute of the root Project element to
>    'Microsoft.NET.Sdk'.  MyApp   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.103\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets   376
> 2. Warning    MSB3270 There was a mismatch between the processor
>    architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor
>    architecture of the reference
>    "C:\Users...\MyLib\bin\x64\Debug\MyLib.dll",
>    "AMD64". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider
>    changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through
>    the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures
>    between your project and references, or take a dependency on
>    references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted
>    processor architecture of your project.   MyApp   C:\Program Files
>    (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>    Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets  2123

Comment: Is your UWP Class Library a .NET 5 library? .NET Standard?  Because it should work with .NET Standard, but may not be compatible yet with .NET 5.

Comment: @TamBui how can I check it?

Comment: My bad, I was going down the wrong tangent. Read my answer instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A WPF application cannot reference a UWP class library. In short, the two different platforms or frameworks are not compatible with each other.

You should change the target framework of your class library (`MyLib.csproj`) to either .NET Standard or the same framework that your WPF app targets:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: A WPF application can reference a UWP class library, and can even host UWP controls within the WPF app.  Take a look at 'XAML Islands' and you'll see that it is possible.  Of course, all of this should be increasingly moot once WinUI 3 comes out.

Comment: I know it's possible to host UWP controls in a WPF app but you should still not reference a UWP class library from a desktop app.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `AssetTargetFallback` that matches your UWP project's target version to your WPF project's `PropertyGroup`.  Select your WPF project in the Solution Explorer, and you will be able to edit the project's properties.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  <RootNamespace>_68824006</RootNamespace>
  <AssetTargetFallback>uap10.0.19041</AssetTargetFallback>
  <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Please see my updated post. There is no compiler errors anymore after following your suggestion but now getting build error.

Comment: Those are warnings, not errors. To get rid of the first warning, edit the first line in your project to say `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk"`. To get rid of the second warning, you need to match your WPF project's platform architecture to your UWP project's architecture. To do that, right-click your Solution in Solution Explorer and choose "Configuration Manager..."

Comment: anyway the build error is frustrating me. Anyway to know where is the problem?

Comment: What is the build error you're getting?  In your previous comment, you stated "There is no compiler errors anymore after following your suggestion".  Then, you posted two warnings.  I don't see you posted any build error, unless I'm missing it?